# Aurelia: Bind to Custom Element Properties using Object

Tags: javascript, mvvm, aurelia, custom-element

If i have an object in my view model that has all the `@bindable` property values for a custom element, can I bind/pass those individual properties in the view to the custom element without binding/passing the entire view-model data object on the custom element?

view-model

```
export class MyViewModel {
  data = { foo: 1, bar: 2 }
}
```

current view

```
<foo foo.bind="data.foo" bar.bind="data.bar></foo>
```

custom element

```
export class FooCustomElement {
  @bindable foo;
  @bindable bar;
}
```

i understand the next snippet wont work, but it shows what i am trying to do. In reality I have a bunch of `@bindables` that are automatically generated and that data object in the view model could have one or many values for the custom element.

```
 <foo something.bind="...data"></foo>
```

I understand I can pass the `data` object from my view model to the custom element, but I was trying to be more explicit in my custom elements.

Comment: Really struggling to get my head around what you're asking? I'm guessing you don't want to explicitly pass all of your variables through the custom element (as you don't know what they are) - but you still want them as individual properties in your CustomElement's VM?

Comment: yes that is correct. i know it seems strange, and there are ways around it of course (such as having one bindable object property and then iterate through that objects properties to set the values of the other bindables). However, i just wanted to see if there were better methods.